# como puedo formular la siguiente consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Actualmente tengo la siguiente consulta
tengo 3 tablas Paciente, Doctor y ventas, en la de ventas se registra cada venta de cada paciente, el paciente tiene un identificador llamado TarjetaID, y Medicotratante que es un ID del medico tipo INT, y la venta trae los campos TarjetaID y el nombre del paciente y el monto.

```
SELECT 
YEAR(V.VentaFecha)  ANO,
MONTH(V.VentaFecha) MES,
CONCAT(IFNULL(D.DoctorNombre,'sin Medico'),' ',IFNULL(D.DoctorApellido,' ')) DOCTOR,
COUNT(P.TarjetaID) CANTIDAD_PACIENTES,
sum(V.VentaTotal) MONTO
FROM paciente P 
left JOIN doctor D ON D.DoctorID = P.MedicoTratante
left JOIN venta V ON P.TarjetaID = V.TarjetaID
WHERE V.VentaFecha BETWEEN finicial AND ffinal
GROUP by MONTH(V.VentaFecha),D.DoctorID  
ORDER BY `MES`,D.DoctorNombre ASC
```

Esta consulta lo que obtiene es cuantas veces cada paciente compro, pero lo que quiero es saber cuantos pacientes compraron

Comment: Pasa algo que no puedes hacerla en mysql ??

Comment: distinc? Del cliente y poniendo sum para las ventas

Comment: No funciona con el Distinc ya que cuenta cuantas veces esta el cliente en la tabla de ventas, tengo que contar si aparece un paciente en esa tabla, si aparece mas veces no se suma